# How to set an environment variable for google credentials in a heroku app

Tags: node.js, firebase, heroku, firebase-admin

Im using heroku to host an express server that uses `firebase-admin` to update firestore data.

Google docs say:

> When authorizing via a service account, you have two choices for
>   providing the credentials to your application. You can either set the
>   GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable, or you can
>   explicitly pass the path to the service account key in code. The first
>   option is more secure and is strongly recommended.
>
> To set the environment variable:
>
> Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS to the
>   file path of the JSON file that contains your service account key.
>   This variable only applies to your current shell session, so if you
>   open a new session, set the variable again.

I have the JSON file with the service account key downloaded locally. and google says to avoid passing the path to the service account key in code. so how do you actually "set the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS environment variable" for a node.js project running on heroku server? Some details that help elucidate how this works would also be appreciated. How is a local file supposed to be accessed from a remote server, why a path isn't secure etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to go in your account -> project -> settings and like second voice there is `Config Vars`.

Press on `Reveal Config Vars`. Here you can insert the GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS variable.

Comment: The `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS` variable just contains a file path. Where does the actual secrets file go, with the service account key? Does heroku have a place to store it?

Comment: That is all you need. Heroku will read the content of the file and get all the necessary keys.  Just make sure you do NOT use the single quote ' around the file path.